# JavaScript Regex: How to let only 2 decimal floating number through oninput pattern match?

Tags: javascript, regex, floating-point, decimal

I have an input type="text" with an input event handler attached to it, which i would like to use to overwrite the input.value with a "filtered" result of the users' key presses.

Basically i want to write a regular expression that only allows floating numbers (positive or negative) with (optionally) 2 decimal positions.

Here's a [scripted example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpgXyM?editors=1010) of what i'm looking for.

If you hit any key while focusing the input in the example above, the input value will be filtered using a combination of regex and JavaScript.

My test input currently looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="-3c.fvbnj23.79.8fbak-cfb436.sdafosd8r32798s.hdf-5kasjfds-gf..">
```

The input event handler looks like this:

```
document.getElementById('test').oninput = function(){
  var foundDot = false,
      str = '';

  this.value.replace(/^-|\.(?=\d)|\d*/g, function(match){
    if (match === '.' && foundDot === true) {
      return;
    }

    if (match === '.' && foundDot === false) foundDot = true;

    str += match;
  });

  this.value = parseFloat(str).toFixed(2);
}
```

Is it possible to obtain the same result with a regular expressions only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Even better, it can be done without regex at all.</strike>

<strike>Well, okay, one regex.</strike>  I misunderstood that you wanted to preserve digits within non-numeric strings.

All right, fiiiiine, two regexes.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```js
//oninput is too aggressive, it runs on every keystroke making it difficult to type in longer values.

document.getElementById('test').onchange = function(){
  // strip non-numeric characters.
  // First char can be -, 0-9, or .
  // Others can only be 0-9 or .
  var val = this.value.replace(/(?!^[\-\d\.])[^\d\.]/g,'');

  // strip out extra dots. Here I admit regex defeat and resort to slice-and-dice:
  var firstDot = this.value.indexOf('.');
  if (firstDot > -1) {
    val = val.substr(0,firstDot+1) + val.substring(firstDot+1).replace(/\./g,'')
  }
  console.log(val);

  // Finally the easy part: set the precision    
  this.value = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<input id="test">
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for the quick answer. Sadly the "isNaN" part makes your answer invalid. I need to be able to effectively filter out only the digits from the user input and let the end result be a positive or negative floating number. Please check my codepen example for the exact behavior i'm looking for

Comment: `parseFloat()` would be more robust than `Number()` for various cases.

Comment: Hi Daniel, this one is a lot closer, but not quite there yet. After your regex i can still get values with mutiple minus signs and multiple dot signs in it, which evaluates to isNaN in Number() :-( This is the hard part ...

Comment: Heh.  I had just sorted out the multiple negative signs, but you're right, missed the multiple dots.

Comment: Well i tried it with "-3c.fvbnj23.79.8fbak-cfb436.sdafosd8r32798s.hdf-5kasjfds-gf.." and i still got NaN

Comment: Yep. Multiple dots still a problem. Still sorting that out.

Comment: OK.  That's as close as I'm gonna get, somebody smarter than me will have to take it from here

Comment: Daniel, you're awesome. I appreciate your help so much! You indeed get my excepted result, nonetheless not without doing some additional JS coding on the side. As I already had scripted solution myself, I can only thank you for your effort and keep on hoping that someone out there knows a one line regex solution for this. If not, i'm gonna go with the regex / script hybrid

Comment: Btw: some of your ideas i took over to my initial scripted solution. Which do you recon is better in terms of performance, yours or mine?

Comment: It's my own fault for thinking `.tofixed()` was all you needed; once I'd waded in I had to keep going :)   Re performance:  you could throw them onto https://jsperf.com and see what happens, but honestly for clientside validation it hardly matters; either one would be able to run a few thousand times in the time it takes the user to make a keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you can't just use a find/replace on each keystroke.

Find `^([-+]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{0,2})?)`
Replace `$1`

Expanded

```
  ^ 
 (                             # (1 start)
      [-+]? 
      (?:
           \d+ 
           (?:
                \. \d{0,2} 
           )?
        |  
           \. \d{0,2} 
      )?
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Comment: i could do that, given that i had the proper regex to filter out all the junk i could get from the user. i tried your solution but it works only partially: https://regex101.com/r/53saap/1

Comment: @molexus - You have to think outside the box friend. I could append 2 characters to my regex, https://regex101.com/r/IkJrZ7/1, but since you chose a convoluted answer, I'm not going to waste my time.